# Ampersand breaking Widget title

Tags: widgets, title, characters

When adding an ampersand (&) to the Text Widget title, the title breaks at the ampersand position (frontend). So: 'me, myself & I' becomes: 'me, myself ' The ampersand is being stored (correctly) as & in the DB.

What really gets me is the fact that the title is already broken in the output method of the widget (public function widget($args, $instance) { ... )
$instance['title'] is  'me, myself '

Further more, the title is correct / complete on the backend (widget edit page).

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Have you escaped `esc_attr( $title )` before saving?

Comment: This used to be a bug in WP pre 3.0 version. I cannot reproduce it with the standard Text Widget in WP 4.5. So you may have a plugin installed that does unwise things with widget titles.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and accept it. Else this question weill keep popping up as "unsolved".

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION:** So, it turned out (of course) I myself was causing the problem (...) I am getting the widgets with the 'the_widget()' method and sending the instance params along as I go. The params are query-string-style parameters and are of course 'glued' together with ampersands. Now , I wasn't encoding the individual params so the query string was looking like this: '&title=me myself & I&url=...' This was (of course) messing things up!

Took me long enough to figure out, so I hope this helps others when running into similar issues!

Thanx for your help!